# Use HashMap in XMLRPC result

Tags: java, android, hashmap, xml-rpc

I am new in Android development, and I am trying to receive a HashMap in RESULT by using XMLRPC but every time it's crash the application, this is my code please advice me :

```
  Object RESULT =  XMLRPCClient.callEx(methodname,new Object[] {params});
         Map FRESULT= (Map) RESULT;
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: "The application  ...... has stopped unexpectedly Please try again "

Comment: You need to get the actual exception information from Logcat. If it's not immediately obvious what the problem is (my guess is ClassCastException) then someone will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

I have been dealing with this also and managed to get the values this way:

```
try {
    Object[] answer = (Object[]) client.call("call", sessionId, method, params);
    HashMap map = (HashMap) answer[0]; // get first item of the response because in my case the response was an array of Objects with one item in it holding the HashMap
    Object[] records = (Object[]) map.get("records"); // I only needed values from "records" key
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        HashMap record = (HashMap) records[i]; // create another map from the records values, in my case uid's of categories
        Category cat = new Category(); // creating new instance of my Category class
        cat.setCatUid((String) record.get("uid")); // calling a method of the Category class to set Uid to the value from record HashMap
        m_categories.add(cat); // this adds it to my ArrayList<Category>
    }
} catch (XMLRPCException e) {
    Log.e(method, "Exception", e);
}
```

I'm sure it's a mess, I'm noob in Java myself, but it worked for me. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Now the Application pass this peacefully after implementing :

```
 Object RESULT = XmlRpcConnect.ServerCall_a(method,new Object[] {params});
          Map<String, Object> FRESULT= (HashMap<String, Object>) RESULT;
```

with some changes in my XmlRpcConnect Class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
public static Object ServerCall_a(String method, Object[] params){
            XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(server);
            HashMap<String, Object> result=null;
                  try{
            result = (HashMap<String, Object>) client.callEx(method, params);
                                                }
                  catch(XMLRPCFault f){
                      //   result = ("Fault message: " + f.getMessage());
                                                                }
                  catch(XMLRPCException e){
                      // result = ("Exception message: " + e.getMessage());
                                                                }
                       return result;
                                }
```

but when trying to extract the values it's crash again , any advice :

```
              if (FRESULT.get("status") == null) {
                          result = (String) FRESULT.get("status");
                          toastDialog(result);
               }
```